# Recursive Descent Disassembly

Tags: ida, disassembly, assembly

Suppose that `eax` contains a value only when the program is running.

How can a disassembler determine the address of expressions like:
`call eax` using static analysis and Recursive Descent disassembly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How can a disassembler determine the address of expressions like: `call eax` using static analysis and Recursive Descent disassembly?

They can't... The truth is that the recursive traversal algorithm just take into account the static calls (i.e. the calls that link to a static address in the binary).

An instruction such as `call eax` (a.k.a. *dynamic call*) can be resolved only by a dynamic analysis or a symbolic execution framework.

Comment: This is not true in many cases for MSVC or MinGW, where the address of the api is moved into a register before it calls the api. Obviously this is not always the case, but if it is you don't need anything fancy to do the analysis...

Comment: @mrexodia: Hum, I think we are not speaking about the same thing... MSVC and MinGW are compilers and I was speaking about disassemblers... Or, I might have missed something, then tell me what you mean. :-)

Comment: I meant that certain compilers emit predictable disassembly that allow you to predict what function will be called for the "call eax" instruction without doing much fancy things.

Comment: Ah, I got it now! Yes, this is true, but it would require a specific heuristic on the disassembler side to take this into account. My point was that the recursive traversal algorithm cannot handle dynamic calls (and, I should maybe have added, as you suggest, "*except in the case of few heuristics that can be added in specific contexts*"). But, all of these heuristics can be defeated or fooled if I change slightly the way I am building the binary. So, you cannot really trust it at the end.